# Why cat command doesn't use its command environment?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, cat

AFAIK, `cat` is an external command and it forks off a new process when executed, just like `sh -c` or executing a script. With that said I expect `cat` to  use its command environment as it is used by other external command, like

```
f=test.txt sh -c 'cat "$f"'
```

Shouldn't this display the content of the file

```
f=test.txt cat $f
```

?

---

Note: I am not asking what is  `someVariable=someValue command`. I am asking why first example uses its command variable but not the second one. The way variable expansion is happening in second example it should happen in first example.

Comment: I'm not having any problems with this command. I get the contents of the file "test.txt", as expected.

Comment: I don't. `echo foo > test.txt; f=test.txt cat $f` waits for input from stdin rather showing `foo`.

Comment: @PhilipKendall; That's exactly what happening with me.

Comment: Why it is dupe? I am not asking what is `someVariable=someValue command `.

Comment: I misunderstood which statement you were asking about. Your second command won't work because the assignment is applied after the statement is executed, not before. See my solution for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Your question is why `f=test.txt cat $f` doesn't display the content of the file (these are your own words) so clearly a dupe. And you don't know the difference between single quotes and double quotes (that would make it also a duplicate of another question so double-dupe)

Answer (score 6):

### Summary

The command `f=test.txt sh -c 'cat "$f"'` produces output because the variable assignment `f=test.txt` occurs before the expansion of the (single-quoted) command-argument `'cat "$f"'`. The single-quotes prevent the expansion from taking place until the subcommand `cat "$f"` is executed.

The command `f=test.txt cat $f` does *not* produce output because the variable assignment `f=test.txt` occurs *after* the expansion of the (unquoted) command-argument `$f`.

### Why `f=test.txt cat $f` does not produce any output

First I'll attempt to explain why the command `f=test.txt cat $f` is not producing any output despite your expectation that it would. Here there might be some slight confusion about the order of evaluation in what's called a [simple command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_01).

You may have assumed that the variable assignment in the prologue of the command (i.e. the `f=test.txt` assignment) occurs before the variable expansion in the body of the command (i.e. the expansion of `$f` in `cat $f`). But this is actually not the case. To verify this we can refer to the page on [simple command expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Command-Expansion.html) in the Bash Manual or to the [subsection on simple commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) in the [Posix Specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). Both of these references include the following passage:

> A "simple command" is a sequence of optional variable assignments and redirections, in any sequence, optionally followed by words and redirections, terminated by a control operator.
>
> When a given simple command is required to be executed (that is, when any conditional construct such as an AND-OR list or a **case** statement has not bypassed the simple command), the following expansions, assignments, and redirections shall all be performed from the beginning of the command text to the end:
>
> 1. The words that are recognized as variable assignments or redirections according to [Shell Grammar Rules](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_02) are saved for processing in steps 3 and 4.
> 2. The words that are not variable assignments or redirections shall be expanded. If any fields remain following their expansion, the first field shall be considered the command name and remaining fields are the arguments for the command.
> 3. Redirections shall be performed as described in [Redirection](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07).
> 4. Each variable assignment shall be expanded for tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal prior to assigning the value.

Notice that step 2 is where the variable expansion in the command occurs, but step 1 tells us that the variable assignments are saved until steps 3 and 4. It follows that the expression `cat $f` is expanded to `cat` (with no arguments) before the assignment `f=test.txt` takes place. This explains why you're not getting any output.

For further discussion on this topic see the following posts:

- [Why is setting a variable before a command legal in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126938/why-is-setting-a-variable-before-a-command-legal-in-bash)
- [bash script's temporary value on command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/266303/bash-scripts-temporary-value-on-command)

### Why `f=test.txt sh -c 'cat "$f"'` *does* produce output

Next I'll attempt to explain why the command `f=test.txt sh -c 'cat "$f"'` *does* produce output. For this we'll want to look at [the full list of general operations performed by the shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_0):

> 1. The shell reads its input from a file (see [sh](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html)), from the -c option or from the [system()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html) and [popen()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/popen.html) functions defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2008. If the first line of a file of shell commands starts with the characters "#!", the results are unspecified.
> 2. The shell breaks the input into tokens: words and operators; see [Token Recognition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03).
> 3. The shell parses the input into simple commands (see [Simple Commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01)) and compound commands (see [Compound Commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04)).
> 4. The shell performs various expansions (separately) on different parts of each command, resulting in a list of pathnames and fields to be treated as a command and arguments; see [wordexp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wordexp.html#).
> 5. The shell performs redirection (see [Redirection](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07)) and removes redirection operators and their operands from the parameter list.
> 6. The shell executes a function (see [Function Definition Command](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05)), built-in (see [Special Built-In Utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14)), executable file, or script, giving the names of the arguments as positional parameters numbered 1 to n, and the name of the command (or in the case of a function within a script, the name of the script) as the positional parameter numbered 0 (see [Command Search and Execution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01_01)).
> 7. The shell optionally waits for the command to complete and collects the exit status (see [Exit Status for Commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_02)).

So you can see here that calling a function/built-in/executable/script (step 6 on this list) occurs *after* parsing of the simple command. Therefore the assignment `f=test.txt` occurs *before* the program execution `sh -c 'cat "$f"'`. And because the argument is single-quoted it is only parsed *after* the command executes. Therefore the subcommand expands to `cat "test.txt"`.

Comment: With the rules above `f=test.txt cat '$f'` should work?

Comment: @haccks No, because in the command `f=test.txt cat '$f'` the variable `f` will never be expanded. That command is going to try to apply `cat` to a file literally named `$f`, i.e. the same as if you'd escaped the dollar-sign `cat \$f`. The reason that the command `f=test.txt sh -c 'cat "$f"'` works is because of the `sh` command. That causes the argument `cat "$f"` to undergo its own round of parsing.

Comment: I read [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/56449/186463), it says that expansion will happen in case of `TEST=foo echo $TEST`. Then why not in the above example of mine? Is there any rule where variables will be expanded and where it will not?

Comment: @haccks You should say specifically which command you're talking about, otherwise I can't be sure what you mean. The command `f=test.txt cat '$f'` has the variable expression contained in single-quotes. Single-quotes prevent variable expansion from taking place. In the command `TEST=foo echo $TEST` the variable expansion occurs because the variable expression is unquoted; however the expansion occurs *before* the assignment, so it likely does not have the intended effect. To get the intended effect you could do this `TEST=foo sh -c 'echo $TEST'`.

Comment: That means in case of `sh -c` there are two round of parsing apart from the parsing of command `TEST=foo sh -c 'echo $TEST'` which will be done by parent shell , is it?

Comment: @haccks That's correct. When the command `sh -c 'echo $TEST'` is invoked it executes the command `echo $TEST` inside of a subshell. This kicks off another round of parsing and expansion. The variable assignment `TEST=foo` has already taken place and is automatically exported to the subshell environment, as described in the subsection on simple commands.

Comment: AFAIK, `sh -c` doesn't invoke subshell, but a child process. If `sh -c` will invoke a subshell and parsing is happening twice then that will hold true for `(TEST=foo echo '$TEST')` (which seems that parsing only once).

Comment: @haccks I believe that `sh -c` does invoke the command in a subshell. A subshell also happens to be a child process - this isn't a contradiction. The parenthesized command `(TEST=foo echo '$TEST')` (i.e. a compound command) also spawns a subshell.

Comment: @haccks Anyway, I don't think your reasoning is correct. The expression `(TEST=foo echo '$TEST')` would be equivalent to `sh -c "TEST=foo echo '\$TEST'"`, but it is *not* equivalent to the expression in question, namely `TEST=foo sh -c 'echo $TEST'`. In the parenthetical syntax (i.e. with a compound command) this might have looked like `TEST=foo (echo $TEST)`, but the shell parser doesn't support this syntax for compound commands.

Comment: [This](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell) says that `sh -c` does not spawn a subshell but it's just a child process (last example). Also see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/261661/186463).

Comment: @haccks It's true that I wasn't wasn't distinguishing between a child shell and a subshell, but I really don't think that's relevant here. You used the term "child *process*" before, which is what I was responding to. In any event, the examples that we've been discussing involved exporting a variable assignment, so the sub-shell vs child-shell distinction shouldn't affect anything in a critical way. I believe that all of my previous comments explain the situation. If you think the child-shell vs subshell distinction is important feel free to elaborate on that.

Comment: @igal: Why do you refer to ``sh -c 'cat "$f"'`` as a “function execution”? Step 6 says “The shell executes a function …, built-in …, executable file, or script”, and `sh` and `cat` are clearly executable files and not functions.

Comment: @haccks: Since nobody else seems to have pointed this out yet (and, if somebody has and I overlooked it, I apologize) — the problem with your quote from [peterph’s answer to “How do I set an environment variable on the command line and have it appear in commands?”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56444/80216#56449) is that you’re misquoting it. *That* answer says that `TEST=foo; echo $TEST` will output `foo`. But now you’re asking about `TEST=foo echo $TEST` — ***not** the same command.* … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  While you’re still learning shell grammar, you might want to get into the habit of using copy and paste, because tiny differences can be more significant than you might guess. Just as ``'… $var …'`` is different from ``"… $var …"``, so also is *```assignment ```* **``; ``** *``command``* different from *``assignment  command``*.

Comment: @G-Man I was using "function" generically - not a good idea in this case, given the context. I've updated my post to be more precise.

Comment: @G-Man; Man! You are hunting me down all over the SE sites!!! :D I appreciate your effort and willingness to help. Actually I wasn't misquoted `TEST=foo; echo $TEST` by `TEST=foo  echo $TEST`, it was intentional.  This example is given by OP in the [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/56444/186463).

Answer (score 2):

Variable assignments on a shell command affect only the environment passed to that command, not the executing shell's environment.

You can see this more directly with

```
$ f=1
$ f=2 echo $f
1
$
```

The `echo` ran in an environment where `f` was set to `2`, but the assignments ran in the (under-construction) command's environment, not the shell environment used to construct the command.

It's only assignments without a command that affect the running shell's environment, and it's the shell's environment that's used to construct commands.

Answer (score 0):

Because in your second example, `$f` is expanded by your shell, not by `cat`. Assuming `f` isn't set otherwise in your shell's environment, `$f` expands to the empty string and `cat` then reads from stdin as it would if given no arguments.

In your first example, the `$f` is inside single quotes so it is not expanded by original shell, but *is* expanded by the instance of `sh` which sees `cat "$f"` *and* has `f` set in its environment.

Comment: Why variable expansion is not happening in first example by current shell? AFAIK, shell expands variables before it runs the command.

Comment: @haccks the shell expands variables before it even sets `f`, when you run `f=test.txt cat $f`; so `$f` expands to the empty string in your case (or whatever it was already set to), *then* `f` is assigned the value `test.txt`, then `cat` is run. See the suggested duplicate for details.

Comment: @StephenKitt; I am asking why it is not happening in the first case `f=test.txt sh -c 'cat "$f"'`?

Comment: Are you saying `f=test.txt sh -c 'cat "$f"'` *doesn't* display the contents of `test.txt`? It certainly does on any machine I have trivial access to.

Comment: @PhilipKendall; No. I am not saying that. What I am saying is "why variable expansion happening in `f=test.txt cat $f` while not in `f=test.txt sh -c 'cat "$f"'`?

Comment: OK, I've added something to the second section of my answer.